# Bouncing Ball doesn't appear on page

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I would like to point out that I'm a beginner at this. So please, I hope you don't mind me asking questions to your solutions.

What I'm trying to construct here is a graphical animation of a ball falling to the ground from a height and then slowly, after several subsequent bounces, the ball just rolls on the base of the canvas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>JavaScript examples</title>

<!-- As a shortcut, I included style information here rather than a separate file -->
<style>
canvas { 
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
</style>

<!-- incorporate jQuery  -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- now my written script -->
<script>

$(function(){

// initialise canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

// physical variables
var g = 0.1; // gravity
var fac = 0.8; // velocity reduction factor per bounce
var radius = 20; // ball radius
var color = "#0000ff"; // ball color
var intervalId

function initBall() { 
// initialise position and velocity of ball
var x = 50;
var y = 50;
var horizontalvelocity = 2;
var verticalvelocity = 0;
}

function drawBall() {
with (context){
    clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clear canvas
    fillStyle = color;
    beginPath();
    arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
    closePath();
    fill();
};
};

function render() {
// update velocity
verticalvelocity += g; // gravity

// update position
x += horizontalvelocity;
y += verticalvelocity; 

// handle bouncing
if (y > canvas.height - radius){
y = canvas.height - radius;
verticalvelocity *= -fac;
}

// wrap around
if (x > canvas.width + radius){
x = -radius;
}

// update the ball
drawBall();
};

function init() {
  <!-- get the rendering area for the canvas -->
  context = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
  WIDTH = $('#canvas').width();
  HEIGHT = $('#canvas').height();
  setInterval(update, 1000/60); // 60 frames per second

  initBall();

  <!-- start animation -->
  intervalId = setInterval(render, 10);
}

$(document).ready(init);

</script>

</head>

<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="500"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

I can't seem to detect the errors I made. Your ideas and solutions would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Hit the F12 key while viewing your page in a browser - this will open the developer console in most browsers. Most of your errors should be obvious, then.

Comment: Tried to resolve the matter from the web developer console, but I didn't come out successful. @Tieson

Comment: Update your question, then, to show what you've done so far. You should also be able to create either a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [Stack Snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) of your code to demonstrate your current issue.

Comment: Here is the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/xzrs49mc/

Comment: How do I attach this into my HTML code? I'm aware that you can save the code as a .js file but I'm just curious how to make this possible without the need to link a separate file. When I put the code in between `<script>` and `</script>`, it doesn't seem to run anymore. @Shomz

Comment: It has to run, here it is in HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/rpbe91at/ You have another error in your code then. Make sure the script runs AFTER the canvas element is defined, either by putting the script after the canvas or by using some of the onload handlers.

Comment: Oh. Before you spotted the error, I had my canvas element placed after the script has been defined but why the order in which the canvas element and script is arranged matters? @Shomz

Comment: Because the script is looking for the canvas element here: `var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');` and if the script runs before the canvas is there, it simply won't find it.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue relates to a scope issue : you are using x,y variables through all your code, so they should be global variables. But your issues are 1) is that you didn't declare them as global variable and 2) when you initialize x,y in initBall, you declare 2 local vars that are x,y, that will hide x,y global vars.

--> add with global scope :

```
var x,y ;
```

(by the way declare also

```
var horizontalvelocity = 2;
var verticalvelocity = 0;
```

)

--> remove the var declaration in

```
function initBall() { 
  // initialise position and velocity of ball
  x = 50;
  y = 50;
  horizontalvelocity = 2;
  verticalvelocity = 0;
}
```

Comment: I already did the changes which you suggested but sadly, it's still not working :( @GameAlchemist

Comment: This answer is good, here is the working version:  http://jsfiddle.net/xzrs49mc/ I wanted to add this to my answer, but this one came up in the meanwhile... Another thing to fix was to remove the setInterval call which call the non-existing `update` function.

Comment: Thks @Shomz, i was also fixing a few other issues here : http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/f3spwux8/  To iJava : it is vital that you build your application step by step, checking at each step that everything is working so far. And keep an eye on the console : your code must always 'compile', you have much better  seing and fixing a typing error early.